# Error binding Image type property with Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0

I have a class with an Image property:

```
...
public Image m_coverImage;
public Image CoverImage
{
    get { return m_coverImage; }
    set
    {
        m_coverImage = value;
        //OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CoverImage"));
    }
}
...
```

Which I bind to an UserControl (named FullDescription) with a Popup:

```
...
<ContentControl Margin="5,0,20,0"
    Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    Content="{Binding CoverImage}"/>
...
```

The Image is previously loaded and is exhibited correctly in a parent Control (binded same way as above), but when I try to bind it to the FullDescription UserControl...

```
...
FullDescription descriptionPopup = new FullDescription();
descriptionPopup.DataContext = this.Ebook; //This line throw error
...
```

...I get an ArgumentException error:

System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message=The parameter is incorrect. 
  StackTrace:
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(INativeCoreTypeWrapper obj, DependencyProperty property, DependencyObject doh)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(INativeCoreTypeWrapper doh, DependencyProperty property, Object obj)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetObjectValueToCore(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RefreshExpression(DependencyProperty dp)
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.RefreshExpression()
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SendDataToTarget()
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourceAquired()
       at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.DataContextChanged(Object o, DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.NotifyDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.NotifyDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.NotifyDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.NotifyDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.NotifyDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.NotifyDataContextChanged(DataContextChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyProperty dp)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications(DependencyProperty dp, Object newValue, Object oldValue)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet, Boolean isSetByStyle, Boolean isSetByBuiltInStyle, PropertyInvalidationReason reason)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
       at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
       at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.set_DataContext(Object value)
       at Mobiltec.Atheneum.Reader.WindowsPhone.Controls.EbookPhotoSummary.hplMore_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
       at System.Windows.Controls.HyperlinkButton.OnClick()
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
       at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, String eventName)
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr lpPrevWndFunc, IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.SafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr lpPrevWndFunc, IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.WindowMessageHooker.Hook.WndProc(IntPtr msgWnd, UInt32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

---

I managed to solve the problem. Changed

```
<ContentControl Margin="5,0,20,0"
Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
Content="{Binding CoverImage}"/>
```

for

```
<Image Margin="5,0,20,0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding CoverImage.Source}"/>
```

and everything works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the errors provided by the Silverlight framework are often very vague, as is the case here.

The best advice I can give you is to narrow down the problem. Simplify your code so that it is the smallest example that exhibits this problem. If you can provide a concise example, updates your question. At the moment it is far to vague to answer.